Title in one line but if too wide for the screen then in two lines with gap between lines


title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 2.2%;
}
<div class="title-wrapper">
  <div class="upper-title">
    DYNAMICALLY ADDING TITLE
  </div>
  <div class="lower-title">
    DYNAMICALLY ADDING TITLE
  </div>
</div>



how to make so that upper-title and lower-title are side by side as long as it is POSSIBLE with little gap between them (i.e. 5px) BUT if they are too wide for a screen when side by side they will go into 2 lines and gap between them should be 18px. So 18px gap only when in two lines!
I've also tried using display: grid but then gap is 18px when side by side as well.
I also tried to make div class=vertical-line and put it inside title-wrapper where I would get the same result as with flex and grid.
The problem is that I have this border-left and it should be the same height as title-wrapper, that is why I can't use margin-bottom on upper-title, it won't look good when title is on one line.

gap: 18px 5px ?

@TemaniAfif I have tried that but the title needs to be in one line if possible, if too wide then it should be in 2 lines and then your comment helps. First I have to make the title in one line.

I solved it with help of @TemaniAfif answer. I just added gap: 18px 5px; and on title-wrapper's parent element add width 100%. Thank you for help!
